# Animate svg rect on button click

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, svg

I want to animate the width of a svg rect.

Initially, rect width should be 0, on button click the width should grow in 5 seconds to 100% of the width.

I create this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-https-n0yi2).

I basically create this class:

```
.grow {
  animation: growAnimation 5s linear 1;
}

@keyframes growAnimation {
  from {
    transform: scale(0%, 100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(100%, 100%);
  }
}
```

I assign this class only when user clicks on button but it doesn't work: rect width is 0 and on click is 100%, there is no growing during 5 seconds.
Why?

Is there a better way to to this? In the future I have to do also a press and hold animation:

- on button click the animation start
- on button hold the animation continue
- if user releases the button before the growing animation ends, then there is the inverse animation (from 100% to 0%).

Comment: Have you looked at [`react-move`](https://github.com/react-tools/react-move). It is an awesome library to simplify animations. Here is a [`CodeSandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-move-z98go) I created a while ago where you can play with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass parameters to `scale` property as number not as percentage:

```
@keyframes growAnimation {
  from {
    transform: scale(0, 1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}
```

[See this Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-hodgkin-b2xyo)